# Crystal Reports (Visual Studio 2010) - please help with page template

Tags: crystal-reports

We are trying to create Crystal Report but have a problem with page template creation.
Report looks like this:
It should be "stamp" in the right bottom corner of page. First page stamp looks little different from other pages stamp.

At the left part of page on the left margin two objects are placed. Both of them oriented vertically and should work as header and footer (should be shown on every page) but take more room than required for usual header and footer. In this case we can't use usual header and footer to place these objects.

Tables on pages should work as "background" because even 1 record on page should show 20-row table (with first row filled in this example)

It would be great if we have something like "left running title" but we can't see such feature in CR.

I attached couple images to show how the report should look (sorry, i can't post images here because have no enough reputation points):

[First Page](http://u.askdev.ru/4e0/a992/7af4aa/large.gif) [Second Page](http://u.askdev.ru/4e0/a993/921b1e/large.gif)

Could you please say how such report template can be created? We have no skilled CR developer in our company and have no idea which way of report creation can be used :(
We also agree to use another report engine if it is free and can work with .NET applications

Thanks for help
Dmitry

Comment: Are you saying that you need something in the header and footer that should work as a background to the report or be available in the left margin? Is the content fixed for each page?

Comment: I need top-left (static) text placed on the left margin of page. It should looks as part of header where part of it prints at the left side of the details section.
In the left bottom small table (placed on the page left margin also) we should place some information as page number and some variables defined as parameters (like document creator etc.)
Main report area should contain table where num of rows are fixed (first page has ~20 rows, other pages have ~25 rows). It should work as background, just few rows would be filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use underlay property of the sections to get the desired result. You can use the page header and page footer for putting the details and for page-header, set the underlay property to TRUE and for the footer, set the property of the detail section (I presume, you have a single detail section in the report) to TRUE. This will make the details of the header and footer display beneath the detail section.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It seems we are on the right way! But we tried to turn this section property on but when we place static text on the header section vertical size automatically grows to match this text area size. How we can reduce header (footer) size to allow the header (footer) text be printed in the details area?

Comment: Have you set the underlay property to tru for the header? If yes, when you preview, you will see the text as you wished to have.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now. We tried with the first version of report which we used to play with report settings and it didn't help. But it works correctly with the new one.
We have more questions but need to clarify them more detail before ask. This problem is resolved already :)